# Laravel Middleware not redirecting to specific route for logged in users

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 7 and have my middleware for both admin and student. When logging in, It redirects them to the home page, which throws a 404 not found error. I want Admins to go to admin.dashboard and students to go to users.dashboard. once logged in in either case, I can access their respective pages. Obviously, I am missing something. If anyone can help me spot where I have gone wrong, I would sure appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });
    Route::get('registered-user', 'Admin\RegisteredController@index');

    Route::get('/quizzes', 'Admin\QuizzesController@index');

    Route::post('save-quiz', 'Admin\QuizzesController@store');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isStudent']], function () {
    Route::get('/student', function () {
        return view('users.dashboard');
    });
});
```

StudentMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class StudentMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'student') {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
}
```

AdminMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('/home')->with('status', 'You are not allowed to access the Admin Dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

The two lines in my Kernel.php

```
'isAdmin' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
'isStudent' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\StudentMiddleware::class,
```

I never changed anything in my RedirectIfAuthenticated.php. It is as was installed.

If I am missing anything, please let me know so I can edit my query. Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use an auth gate to achieve this. In your AuthServiceProvider:

```
 Gate::define('is-student', function ($user) {
        return $user->role_as == 'student';
    });
```

And in your route or controller

```
if(Gate::allows('is-student')
    return view('users.dashboard')
```

And so on for other roles..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Bennett. Unfortunately, it gave the same results. So I am definitely missing something.

Comment: Just to confirm - did you remove the middleware and auth clauses from the route when you tried this?

Comment: Yes, well, at least I commented them out.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question, I was missing the following in my LoginController.php replacing `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;` with

```
public function redirectTo()
    {
        // Admin Login
        if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'admin') {
            return 'admin';
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'student') {
            return 'student';
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps if someone else runs into this same issue.